# can anyone explain this error and also about this case too like why I cant equivalate that two values?

Tags: string

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(remove(str));
}

static String remove(String str)   
  { 
      int start=0;
       if(str.charAt(0)!=str.charAt(1)){
           return str;
       }
         if(str.charAt(0)=str.charAt(1)){
             str=str.substring(start+1,str.length());
             remove(str);  
         }
  } 
  
  }
```

/Root/src/Main.java:22: error: unexpected type
if(str.charAt(0)=str.charAt(1)){
^
required: variable
found:    value
1 error

Comment: `str.charAt(0)=str.charAt(1)` -> `str.charAt(0)==str.charAt(1)` - You need a comparison operator

Comment: Ohh silly mistake ...let me try this..thanks for yr response